# Unable to update text of a field based on lookup value selection in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a leave list where I need to do the leaves calculations. I have placed the 'number of leaves' field in the 'user information' list.

I want the add new leave form which should extract the available leave from 'user information' list (i.e. 'number of leaves'), so that I can subtract the applied leaves from it and update back to the 'number of leaves' field in the crresponding 'user information' list (Created By).

Not sure how should we do this, may be after creating a leave record this can be done by workflow. I have tried all posiblities, but no luck.
Please provide the steps if you can able to help me on this,

Comment: Please also include what all approaches you have tried so far.

Comment: There are two different list 1. User information list 2. Leave list. I have put a column 'no of leaves' in the user infomation list. I want when user fill the new leave form, it should display 'No of leaves' from user information list.

Comment: I don't know how I'll be able to do this, so just asking for it. Please advise